# Functions running in different order than what I put in

Tags: c, excel

First off thank you for taking the time for reading this post.  I almost have this program figured out but there is problem that I can't seem to shake.  Here's the program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

    FILE *fp;
    char str[100];
    char* filename;
    char* filename = str;
    int timer;


struct Pumps
{
    char cityname[30];
    int volume;
    float priceperpump;
    float priceperactiv; /*150 dollars each time the pump turns on*/
    int activated;
    int hourInput;
    int hourOutput;
};

struct Pumps Pumps1;
struct Pumps Pumps2;
struct Pumps Pumps3;
struct Pumps Pumps4;

void functionInput(void)
{
    /*City 1*/
    strcpy(Pumps1.cityname, "Valdez");
    Pumps1.priceperactiv = 210;

    /*City 2*/
    strcpy(Pumps2.cityname, "Glenallen");
    Pumps2.priceperactiv = 210;

    /*City 3*/
    strcpy(Pumps3.cityname, "Tok");
    Pumps3.priceperactiv = 210;

    /*City 4*/
    strcpy(Pumps4.cityname, "Fairbanks");
    Pumps4.priceperactiv = 210;
}

int uniform_distribution_ranges(int rangeLow, int rangeHigh)
{
    double myRand = rand()/(1.0 + RAND_MAX);
    int range = rangeHigh - rangeLow +1;
    int myRand_Scaled = (myRand * range ) + rangeLow;
    return myRand_Scaled;
}


void volumefinal( struct Pumps pump );

int main(void)
{


    printf("\n Enter the filename :");

    gets(str);

    printf("\n Creating %s.csv file",str);

    filename=strcat(filename,".csv");

    functionInput();

    fp=fopen(filename,"w");

volumefinal( Pumps1 );
volumefinal( Pumps2 );
volumefinal( Pumps3 );
volumefinal( Pumps4 );

fclose(fp);

return 0;

}

void volumefinal( struct Pumps pump )
{

    fp=fopen(filename,"a");

    fprintf(fp,"%s,\t",pump.cityname);

    int rangeLow, rangeHigh;

    /* Define Volume, initial with uniform distribution */
    rangeLow=40;
    rangeHigh=80;

    pump.volume = uniform_distribution_ranges(rangeLow, rangeHigh);

    /*Define Input,  with uniform distribution */
    rangeLow=4;
    rangeHigh=10;

    pump.hourInput = uniform_distribution_ranges(rangeLow, rangeHigh);  

    /*Define Output,  with uniform distribution */
    rangeLow=15;
    rangeHigh=20;

    pump.hourOutput = uniform_distribution_ranges(rangeLow, rangeHigh); 

    srand ( time(0) );

    for(timer=0;timer<24;timer++)
    {

    /*Define input,with uniform distribution */

        pump.activated = (rand()% 2);   
        if(pump.volume < 45)
        {
            pump.activated = 0;
            pump.volume = pump.volume + pump.hourInput;
        }

        else
        {
            pump.activated = 1;
            pump.volume = pump.volume + pump.hourInput - pump.hourOutput;
        }

        fprintf(fp,"%d,\t",pump.activated);
        fprintf(fp,"%d,\t",pump.volume);

    }
    fprintf(fp,"\n");
}
```

So the program is supposed to simulate a pump operation for 24 hour period with 1 hour increments recording whether the pump was on or off each hour and its resulting volume. Each city and its entry would be on a different row and the order should be Valdez Glenallen Tok and Fairbanks. However when I run the program the order from top to bottom becomes Fairbanks Valdez Glenallen and Tok.  Even more vexing is I can change the order that the 
volumefinal ( Pumps1 ),volumefinal ( Pumps2 ),volumefinal ( Pumps3 ),volumefinal ( Pumps4 ) 
to
volumefinal ( Pumps4 ),volumefinal ( Pumps3 ),volumefinal ( Pumps2 ),volumefinal ( Pumps1 )

And on the excel sheet the orders  of the city stay  Fairbanks Valdez Glenallen and Tok.  Additionally it appears that the last two rows are the same even though they should have random values.  I honestly can't see what I am missing any help would be much appreciated.  Thank you for your time.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to reopen the file each time in:

```
void volumefinal( struct Pumps pump )
```

If you remove that call it works fine:

```
    void volumefinal( struct Pumps pump )
    {
        // fp=fopen(filename,"a"); <----

        fprintf(fp,"%s,\t",pump.cityname);

        int rangeLow, rangeHigh;
        // ..
    }
```

Comment: I tried removing that line before however it won't compile if you do because fp is not defined then within the function, the a is to append the the file instead of creating a new one. I will try closing the file within that block and see what happens.

Comment: @AKNorth `fp` is a global variable, and that line wasn't a declaration anyway

Comment: That did the trick, thanks you got me headed in the right direction, so the problem was with C you can't open the same file twice in a row without problems. instead you can open it apend it, close it and then open and apendit again. To solve this I just added fclose(fp); into the void volumefinal( struct  Pumps pump)